Maximum number of directed edges before some vertices can be obtain through transitivity
I have a complete directed graph, T, with 2 $ \binom{n}{2} $ edges, i.e for every 2 nodes i, j we have $i\rightarrow j$ and $j\rightarrow i$. For clarity, number the vertices 1 to n.
Question is, what is the maximum number of edges we can choose before we have no choice but to choose an edge that can be obtain from transitivity from the previous chosen edges.
Firstly, the order matters. Suppose I choose 1 $ \rightarrow $ 2 and 1 $ \rightarrow $ 3, I can still choose 2 $\rightarrow $ 3 , because with just the previous 2 edges, I cannot travel from 2 to 3
The maximum I suspect is $ \binom{n+1}{2} $ - 1
First we start with a Hamiltonian path 1 $ \rightarrow $ 2 $ \rightarrow $3 ... $ \rightarrow $ n
Then starting from 2, I connect edge 2 $ \rightarrow $ 1
For 3, do 3 $ \rightarrow $ 2 and 3 $ \rightarrow $ 1
For 4, do 4 $ \rightarrow $ 3, 4 $ \rightarrow $ 2, 4 $ \rightarrow $ 1
We cannot do better, as with the hamitonian path presented, we cannot have i $ \rightarrow $ j, where i < j. But the arrows from the next steps all form a complte graph, just that the arrows can only point from i $ \rightarrow $ j where i > j.
I hope you get the idea, and the total number of edges is $ \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i $ + n - 1, doing some simple manipulation you can get $ \binom{n+1}{2} $ - 1
Can anyone help me prove that the max is the best we can do?

If you choose $1 \to 2$ and $1 \to 3$, is there a problem with choosing $2 \to 3$? Then the edge $1 \to 3$ can be obtained by transitivity from chosen edges, but not from previously chosen ones.

For minimum maximal non-transitive arcs subset you have a right guess. The lower bound can be achieved as follows. Every maximal non-transitive arcs subset induces a subgraph, that is spanning (i. e., containing every vertex) and strongly connected (i. e., each vertex is reachable from each other). Therefore there should be at least $n$ arcs, since each vertex should have at least one outgoing and one incoming arc. Also Hamiltonian cycle is the only subgraph (up to multiplicity) which meets this lower bound.
But for maximum non-transitive arcs subset you idea is far from optimal (at least for all $n \ge 8$). We can split vertex set into a left part with $p = \left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor$ vertices and a right one with $q = \left\lceil\frac n2\right\rceil$ vertices. Then we take all arcs going from the left part to the right one, $pq = \left\lfloor\frac{n^2}{4}\right\rfloor$ in total. At this point I don't have an appropriate upper bound so may be my answer is still not optimal.
